# Error while starting Mongod with config file option

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to start mongod servers with replication using config file.
when issue the command

> mongod --config /etc/mongod1.conf

throws an error-

> Unrecognized option: replSet
>
> Unrecognized option: oplogSizeMB

MongoDB Version: 3.0

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongo/test
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid  # location of pidfile

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27030
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Listen to local interface only, comment to listen on all interfaces.


#security:

#operationProfiling:

replication:
replSet: testrep
oplogSizeMB: 1024
#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options
```

please help me.

Comment: Just ident `replSet` and `oplogSizeMB` lines two spaces to the right. That's the thing with yaml

Comment: perfect. thank you :)

Comment: @OriDar you should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ident replSet and oplogSizeMB lines two spaces to the right. That's the thing with yaml

Comment: In my case the name of the property replSet was changed to replSetName. Wise to refer to MongoDB documents based on which version of MongoDB you are using